# Find the elements from table A not included in table B both connected by table C

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, join

I have three tables:

ProductionOrderRow, ProductionOrderRoutingRow and ProductionOrder

ProductionOrderRow contains data like:

```
ProductionOrderRowId / Routing code
1                    / ZIP1 
1                    / MAGR1 
1                    / CSMK1 
1                    / TUFT1
```

ProductionOrderRoutingRow data like:

```
ProductionOrderRoutingRowId / Routing code
1                           / ZIP1 
1                           / MAGR1 
1                           / CSMK1
```

ProductionOrder contains data like:

```
ReferenceNumber / ProductionOrderRoutingRowId / ProductionOrderRowId

000001          / 1                           / 1
```

I want to find all routing code from ProductionOrderRow, which isn't present in ProductionOrderRoutingRow. In my example it's TUFT1. But it's not that simple:

Each ProductionOrder record has a ProductionOrderRow and a ProductionOrderRoutingRow foreign key. So what I want to do is:

- Find the routing codes from ProductionOrderRow that is not present in ProductionOrderRoutingRow in the first ProductionOrder record
- Find the routing codes from ProductionOrderRow that is not present in ProductionOrderRoutingRow in the second ProductionOrder record ... etc

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (somewhat obscure) `SELECT... EXCEPT...` structure can handle this:

```
SELECT
   pr.ReferenceNumber
  ,por.RoutingCode
 from ProductionOrder  pr
  inner join ProductionOrderRow  por
   on por.ProductionOrderRowId = pr.ProductionOrderRowId
EXCEPT SELECT
   pr.ReferenceNumber
  ,porr.RoutingCode
 from ProductionOrder  pr
  inner join ProductionOrderRoutingRow  porr
   on porr.ProductionOrderRoutingRowId = pr.ProductionOrderRoutingRowId
```

Think of this as:

- the first "select" pulls out all the **Row** RoutingCodes for all Reference Numbers
- the second "select" pulls out all the **RoutingRow** RoutingCodes for all Reference numbers
- and the "except" removes all items from the second set found in the first set

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select por.* 
from ProductionOrderRow por
where not exists (
    select 1
    from ProductionOrderRoutingRow porr
    inner join ProductionOrder po 
        on po.ProductionOrderRoutingRowId = porr.ProductionOrderRoutingRowId 
    where 
        po.ProductionOrderRowId = por.ProductionOrderRowId
        and porr.RoutingCode = por.RoutingCode  
)
```